# Is it possible to split PCAPS into multiple files bases on simple criteria

Tags: pcap

Is it possible to split PCAPS into multiple files bases on simple criteria

Origional.pcap
{split on port 80} which generates the 2 following files

- all_port_80.pcap
- everything_else.pcap

Or would it be easier to create multiple different tcpdumps that match my criteria

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `tcpdump` to read from your capture file and write out a new file:

```
tcpdump -r all.pcap -w port80.pcap port 80 
tcpdump -r all.pcap -w other.pcap ! port 80
```

Comment: Evan that is exactly what I was looking for that is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [PcapSplitter](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/PcapSplitter) which is part of the [PcapPlusPlus](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/) suite. You didn't specify the OS you're interested in but PcapSplitter works in both Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.
You can use it as follows:

`PcapSplitter -f all.pcap -o D:\Output -m bpf-filter -p "port 80"`

It'll output two files: **all-0000.pcap** will contain port 80 packets and **all-0001.pcap** will contain the rest of the packets

Apparently the latest release of PcapPlusPlus doesn't contain this feature so you'll have to compile it yourself from source